# Can we completely change administrator URL for all pages in JOOMLA 4.3.1?

Tags: joomla, joomla4

I am trying to change my administrator URL for all pages in Joomla 4.3.1, but didn't find a proper way to do that.

I have upgraded my Joomla to 4.3.1 from 3.10.1 and before upgrade I had a different administrator URL like example.com/my-admin-path, but now after upgradation it is changes to default as example.com/administrator.

I want to change my administrator URL back to previous URL that worked for all pages.
If anyone have any solution or way to do this, please answer it.